# Does a 1-Lipschitz function preserve mutual information?

Tags: metric-spaces, information-theory

As above, if we have a 1-Lipschitz function $f$, does that imply:

$$I(f(X); f(Y)) = I(X; Y)$$

for some random variables $X$ and $Y$?

I think the main thing is to show $f$ is injective, and use the fact that mutual information is preserved under invertible transformations. But I don't know how to show a 1-Lipschitz function is also an injective one, although it seems intuitive to be so.

Is there a way to prove this?